# Supabase migrations is empty

Tags: supabase

Running the command `supabase migration new initial_migration` creates a new migration file, but it's empty. Whereas, running `supabase db diff --use-migra -f initial_migration` creates a migration file as expected. Not sure why? Can't someone help me with why this happens

Answer (score 0):

It works 100% correct.

'supabase migration new initial_migration' creates an empty file where you can put your own sql code inside.

'supabase db diff --use-migra -f initial_migration' creates a initial_migration.sql file with code represents difference between what is on
your local supabase instance vs code inside your migrations folder.